# Redirect multiple urls through mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, .htaccess, redirect

I was wondering if it would be possible to redirect a url to another specific url that is got from a database? For example if www.mydomain.com/page was entered it would redirect to www.mydomain.com/folder/page and if www.mydomain.com/page2 was entered it would redirect to www.mydomain.com/folder/page2.

At the minute I just have redirects in my 404 page with this code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$page= 'http://www.mydomain.com/page';

if ($url == $page){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header( 'Location: http://www.mydomain.com/folder/page' ) ;
}
?>
```

and I've done this with multiple other pages as well.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sure it is possible. Just get the url from the database and pass is to the location header. Or is this not what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure

you have to first get the url from the database
then redirect it using php's [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `token`= $token');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $result );
header("Location: page/{$row['url']}");
```

replace `your_table` with your table name that contains the redirection rules

however if your redirection rules always consist on adding `/page` before the url, then check the other answers

Comment: ...And consider using either `PDO`, or `MySQLi` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add these into your .htaccess file. It is working fine for me.

```
RedirectMatch ^/page$ /folder/page
RewriteRule ^/page /folder/page [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch ^/page2$ /folder/page2
RewriteRule ^/page2 /folder/page2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need this rule in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /folder/$1 [L,R=302]
```