# How to rewriting URL using database in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have little knowledge of .htaccess file and able to rewrite url. but for huge number of pages and page specific url requirements, i can't define this in .htaccess file. I had to use database for storing different urls of different pages, now i don't have any idea how to use it. I know working of dynamic url rewriting also like rewriting following url

```
www.mysite.com/garments/news.php?id=32
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/garments/news/32
```

but what about random page urls like

```
www.mysite.com/garments/news.php
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/latest-news
```

Comment: I think its duplicate [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679519/redirect-multiple-urls-through-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

To get this link i would use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^latest-news/([0-9]+)/?$    garments/news.php?id=$1
```

What this does is redirect this url:

```
www.mysite.com/latest-news/30/
```

to this:

```
www.mysite.com/garments/news.php?id=30
```